# Can I (server) make the web client send http request with fixed header like version?

Tags: http

I have a question.
I'm planing to serve two version of web service. And I want to make process below

1. There is two version of web service, like `A` and `B`.
2. If a user first access to `A`, I serve the service `A` whenever the user request.

To do above I'll store a version, that user can access, in user database.

The issue I have to solve is that if the server response with a certain version, like `A`, the client request with the version after received the version from server. For example,

1. user send first request
2. server set the version for the user and store it in data base
3. server response with the version in response header
4. user send another request with the version that server send in header
5. the user always send a request with the version after once the server response with the version

It looks like confusing, but the process is like cookie (if the server set the cookie in response once, the client always send the cookie to server for every request).

Is there any way to do it using HTTP header ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do the versioning using custom accept headers like the following:

```
Accept-version: v1
Accept-version: v2
```

It is also possible to use custom vendor type responses if required according to [RFC6838](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838#section-3.2)